# Is there a way I can give column padding to an adaptive card- Adaptive MS BOT

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I'm using an adaptive card to display dynamic content in a  table using the, adaptive-cards templating package.

I have been to customize it but one column is still refusing to fall in place, the column would always have more content than others. So it's falling out of rows, therefore expanding the table and making it look ugly.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
async testTableData(context) {
var tablePayLoad = {
  $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "size": "Medium",
      "text": "Details",
      "horizontalAlignment": "left",
      "separator": true,
    },
    //Databody
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "separator": true,
      "bleed": true,
      "spacing": "Padding",
      "columns": [
        //Name
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,

          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "Name",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "separator": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${Name}",
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
          ],
        },
        //Mobile NO
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,

          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "Mobile No",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "separator": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${MobileNo}",
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
          ],
        },
        //Email Address
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,

          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "Email",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "separator": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${Email}",
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
          ],
        },
        //DOB
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,
          "width": "auto",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "D.O.B",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "separator": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${DOB}",
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
          ],
        },

        //House Address
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,

          "bleed": true,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "Address",
              horizontalAlignment: "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "separator": true,
              wrap: true,
              "size": "small",
              "text": "${HouseAddress}",
              horizontalAlignment: "center",
            },
          ],
        },
        //Location
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,

          "bleed": true,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "Branch",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "separator": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "text": "${Location}",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },

    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "size": "Medium",
      "text": "Trans.",
      "horizontalAlignment": "left",
      "spacing": "extraLarge",
      "separator": true,
    },

    //Trans.
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "separator": true,
      "bleed": true,
      "spacing": "Padding",
      "columns": [
        //Amount
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "separator": true,
          "width": "auto",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "small",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "text": "Amount",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              $data: "${Trans}",
              "separator": true,
              "text": "${Amount}",
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "spacing": "ExtraLarge",
            },
          ],
        },
        //Type
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "auto",
          "separator": true,

          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "small",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "text": "Type",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              $data: "${Trans}",
              "separator": true,
              "text": "${Type}",
              "size": "small",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "spacing": "ExtraLarge",
            },
          ],
        },
        //Currency
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "auto",
          "separator": true,

          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "small",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "text": "Currency",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              $data: "${Trans}",
              "separator": true,
              "size": "small",
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${Currency}",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "spacing": "ExtraLarge",
            },
          ],
        },
        //Date
        {
          "type": "Column",
          //   "bleed": true,
          //   width: "auto",

          "separator": true,

          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "small",
              "text": "Date",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "wrap": true,
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              $data: "${Trans}",
              "separator": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${Date}",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
              "size": "small",
              "spacing": "ExtraLarge",
            },
          ],
        },

        //Comment
        {
          "type": "Column",
          //   width: "stretch",
          "separator": true,
          //   "bleed": true,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "small",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "text": "Comment",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              $data: "${Trans}",
              "separator": true,
              "size": "small",
              "wrap": true,
              "text": "${Comments}",
              "spacing": "ExtraLarge",
              "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

// Create a Template instance from the table payload
var template = new ACData.Template(tablePayLoad);

// Expand the template with your `$root` data object.
// This binds it to the data and produces the final Adaptive Card payload

var data = [
  {
    Amount: "6000",
    Type: "C",
    Currency: "NGN",
    Date: "2019-07-19T00:00:00Z",
    Comments: "Just a regular comment here",
  },
  {
    Amount: "6000",
    Type: "C",
    Currency: "NGN",
    Date: "2019-07-19T00:00:00Z",
    Comments: "Just another Comment here",
  },
];
var dob = new Date("1990-05-29T00:00:00Z");

var tableCardPayload = template.expand({
  $root: {
    Name: "JOHN DOE",
    MobileNo: "2349082182323",
    Email: "admin@doe.com",
    DOB: dob.toLocaleDateString(),
    HouseAddress: "16, Lagos Street, Lagos",
    Location: "Universe",
    Trans: data,
  },
});

const cardToLoad = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(tableCardPayload);

await context
  .sendActivity({ attachments: [cardToLoad] })
  .then()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

},

Comment: If the edit history contains someone's real contact information then you should ask Stack Overflow to redact it for you. They already declined my request because they didn't see evidence that the contact information was real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a table style approach in AdaptiveCards you need to use columnSets. However a columnset is what it is, just one set of columns ie one row of data.

To have a table you need to add one columnset per row, luckily templating can do that for us easily.

You do not need to create any rows manually, you just need to bind the data on the correct place. Have a look at this:

```
{
"schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "size": "Medium",
        "text": "Account Details",
        "horizontalAlignment": "left",
        "separator": true
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "separator": true,
        "bleed": true,
        "spacing": "Padding",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Name",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "text": "${Name}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ],
                "width": "stretch"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Mobile No",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "text": "${MobileNo}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ],
                "width": "stretch"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Email",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "text": "${Email}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ],
                "width": "stretch"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "D.O.B",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "text": "${DOB}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "bleed": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Address",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "${HouseAddress}",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ],
                "width": "stretch"
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "bleed": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Branch",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "text": "${DomicileBranch}"
                    }
                ],
                "width": "stretch"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "size": "Medium",
        "text": "Last Five Transactions",
        "horizontalAlignment": "left",
        "spacing": "ExtraLarge",
        "separator": true
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "separator": true,
        "bleed": true,
        "spacing": "Padding",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "width": 20,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "text": "Amount",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 10,
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "text": "Type",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 20,
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "text": "Currency"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "text": "Date",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ],
                "width": 20
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "text": "Remarks",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                    }
                ],
                "width": 30
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "separator": true,
        "bleed": true,
        "spacing": "Padding",
        "$data": "${lastFiveTrans}",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "separator": true,
                "width": 20,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "text": "${Amount}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "spacing": "ExtraLarge"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 10,
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator": true,
                        "text": "${TransactionType}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "spacing": "ExtraLarge"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 20,
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "${Currency}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "spacing": "ExtraLarge"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 20,
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "${TransactionDate}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "spacing": "ExtraLarge"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 30,
                "separator": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "${Remarks}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "spacing": "ExtraLarge"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

This should do what you want. You had various smaller issues as well.
When using the $data property you need to make sure to use it only once on the element you want to have repeated. In your case you repeated the data over and over again in the same column. Padding, auto spacing etc only works properly when the columns keep their size proportionally to the other elements.

In short:
Build a table with multiple columnsets

- Columnset1 -> Table Headers
- Columnset2-N -> Table Rows
- Columnset3 -> Table footers if you need any

to make it a proper looking table you need to make sure that all columns from header to data have the same width which is done easiest with either pixel width or weighted.

Comment: Works fine & I  learned something new.

But what do I do if the data I'm trying to iterate into the table is large? for medium-sized data, it works fine, but once the data is large it crashed with error `413 RestError: Message size too large.`

Comment: You would have to send multiple cards. Afair theres a limit on card size around 25kb

Comment: Bot Framework don't support v1.3 of adaptive card. Please replace 1.3 with 1.2

Comment: Bot Framework as such supports any type of card. Some hosts don't support 1.3 yet (like MS Teams. WebChat does support 1.3)

Answer (score 2):

I have verified that using rows instead of columns will fix your problem. This means instead of one column set with many elements in each column, you will have many column sets with one element in each column. Each column set will serve as a row and they'll all be stacked on top of each other.

I've written a function that converts columns to rows for you. You can use this or you can make the changes to your card manually. Here's the code:

```
async function sendCard(card) {
    await turnContext.sendActivity(
        MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card))
    );
}

function makeRows(columnSet) {
    const rows = [];

    if (columnSet.columns.length) {
        const numRows = columnSet.columns[0].items.length;
        for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) {
            const row = Object.assign({}, columnSet);
            row.columns = [];

            for (const column of columnSet.columns) {
                const item = column.items[rowIndex];
                const rowColumn = Object.assign({}, column);
                //item.wrap = true;
                rowColumn.items = [item];
                row.columns.push(rowColumn);
            }

            rows.push(row);
        }
    } else {
        rows.push(columnSet);
    }

    return rows;
}

function replaceColumnsWithRows(body) {
    for (let index = body.length - 1; index > -1; index--) {
        const element = body[index];
        if (element.type == "ColumnSet") {
            const rows = makeRows(element);
            body.splice(index, 1, ...rows);
        }
    }
}

var tablePayLoad = {
    $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    type: "AdaptiveCard",
    // Your template
};

// Create a Template instance from the table payload
var template = new ACData.Template(tablePayLoad);

// Expand the template with your `$root` data object.
// This binds it to the data and produces the final Adaptive Card payload

var tableCardPayload = template.expand({
    $root: {
        // Your data
    },
});

await sendCard(tableCardPayload);

replaceColumnsWithRows(tableCardPayload.body);

await sendCard(tableCardPayload);
```

Comment: Works fine, But what do I do if the data I'm trying to iterate into the table is large? for medium-sized data, it works fine, but once the data is large it crashed with error 413 RestError: Message size too large.

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarification about this particular answer to this particular question. If your messages are too large then that's unrelated to this question and you should ask how to resolve that in a new question.

Comment: Okay, Thank You.